# How to replace the current CodeBlock from Markdown-It in Vuepress with my custom CodeBlock Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuepress, markdown-it

I want the markdown-it from Vuepress 2 use my vue codeblock component that I created instead of the [codeblock](https://v2.vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/markdown.html#code-blocks) that comes from markdown-it. When wraping the example code with:

````
```
````

I was wondering if I have to create a plugin that extends the markdown-it.[image: This is the current codeblock from Vuepress Markdown-It]
This is the current codeblock from Vuepress Markdown-It.

Thanks